# Getting the next and preview id for each Json Object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get for all object the preview and the next "id" of each but i receive a blank response:

```
{
   id: "5d810c4e58add1268643cc7c",
   video_url_next: { },
   video_url_prev: { },
},
```

This is the code used:

```
data: docs.map(doc => {
   const next = Video.find({_id: {$gt: doc.id}}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1).exec();
   const prev = Video.find({_id: {$lt: doc.id}}).sort({_id: -1 }).limit(1).exec();
   return {
      id: doc._id
      video_url_next: next,
      video_url_prev: prev,
   }
})
```

Comment: `Video.find()` is async so you need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: Thanks @CuongLeNgoc but what can i do to see the prev and next id for each object?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(next)`

Comment: This `[Function: next]` but i don't know...